# Scale to fit cuts image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have an UIImageView with the image of a gradient with a thin line at the bottom. As the image isn't the same size as the imageview I want to scale it in some way. I don't care if I stretch the image but I would like the line at the bottom to be visible. Therefore I chose "Scale To Fill". But as you can see on the second screenshot the bottom line is not showing up in the simulator.

I thought that "Scale to fill" meant that the image got stretched so that all content is visible but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I highly appreciate your answers!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the image isn't the same size as the imageview I want to scale it in some way. I don't care if I stretch the image

So use a resizable image (`resizableImageWithCapInsets:`). This is exactly what it is for.

> but I would like the line at the bottom to be visible.

Well, there are some extra complications here, and you are not explaining how you are handling them. You have a UIImageView; it has a size. Perhaps *it* is bigger than the view we are seeing in the screen shot. Perhaps it is being overlapped by the text view that we see below it. In other words, it matters how this image view is being placed in the interface and sized.

Comment: I have not assigned the UIImageView to any IBOutlet in my code so it would be handy to only use the Attributes inspector to change the values but maybe that isn't possible?

Comment: The UIImageView is 320x53, the image I want to fit inside is 640x194. The view in the first screenshot displays the full UIImageView.

Comment: So if the first screenshot looks right, why are you doing something different in the second screen shot?

Comment: That is what is weird. The first screenshot is taken from the storyboard in Xcode, a second later when I have pressed Run it shows up differently in the simulator as screenshot 2.

Comment: "The UIImageView is 320x53, the image I want to fit inside is 640x194" So the image is way too large! So if you shrink it to fit the size of the image view, that line is going to get so thin you won't be able to see it (because the device can't draw something smaller than a pixel). What I would do is draw the image the right height in the first place, and make it resizable so that it can stretch horizontally.

Comment: Pls try UIViewContentModeBottom. At least then we will know if the bottom of the image view is showing. The top of the gradient will be lost (because the image is too big), but the line at the bottom of the image will be aligned to the bottom of the image view.

Comment: I made a different image that fitted better now. Thanks for your help!